# Recursive Function: recursion with python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have this Function:

```
def depth(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return 0
        left = depth(self.left)
        right = depth(self.right)
        if left>right:
            return left+1
        else:
            return right+1
```

But when I run it, the following error pops up:

```
 File "/Users/suryakannan/Documents/Python Programs/binaryTree.py", line 60, in depth
    left = depth(self.left)
NameError: name 'depth' is not defined
```

So, what should I do to fix this function?

Comment: Try `self.depth(self.lenght)`,

Comment: shouldn't it be `self.depth` since it's inside a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `depth` is an instance method, you need to use the `self` reference

```
def depth(self):
    if self.root == None:
        return 0
    left = self.depth(self.left)
    right = self.depth(self.right)
    if left>right:
        return left+1
    else:
        return right+1
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. I really appreciate everyone that contributed